# Pointer-interconvertibility of derived and base class objects and the Standard's wording on it

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, casting, standards

I'm trying to understand when I can safely cast a derived object to a base subobject through a pointer to void (I think it should be the same as `reinterpret_cast`). But the Standard's wording on this, which I could find, confuses me. First of all,

> Two objects a and b are pointer-interconvertible if:
>
> — one is a standard-layout class object and the other is the first non-static data member of that object, or, if the object has no non-static data members, the first base class subobject of that object

From this one cannot draw a reliable conclusion whether "or" applies to the whole subsentence before "or" or only to the second part of it. This is important because I can't know for sure if "standard-layout class object" is imperative for pointer-interconvertibility with the base subobject in the case of absence of non-static data members.

But while digging in the Standard further I've found:

> If a standard-layout class object has any non-static data members, its address is the same as the address of its first non-static data member. Otherwise, its address is the same as the address of its first base class subobject (if any).

This seems to be more clear that "standard-layout" is required. But still confusing. Consider the following code:

```
class B { public: int b; };
class C : public B { public: int c; };

int main ()
{ 
    C c;
    B* b = &c;
    std::cout << &c << " address of standard-layout class object\n";
    std::cout << &c.c << " address of its first non-static data member\n";
    std::cout << b << " address of first base class subobject\n";
    return 0;
}
```

On VS2019 the result is:

```
009BFBF8 address of standard-layout class object
009BFBFC address of its first non-static data member
009BFBF8 address of first base class subobject
```

which is not what the Standard says. Can you explain me this?

Comment: for both quotes standard layout is a premise. When I try here, it looks like `C` is not standard layout: https://godbolt.org/z/3W796T

Comment: @idclev, on VS it also gives `false`. But after deletion a member from any of B or C it resolves to `true`.

Comment: do you get what you expect in the case when `C` is standard layout?

Comment: C is not a standard-layout class, so that second paragraph does not say anyhing about your example.

Comment: btw your motivation is a bit unclear. You need no `reinterpret_cast` nor a detour via `void*` to cast between base and derived

Comment: @idclev it's for implementing COM QueryInterface

Comment: @idclev I must return a void pointer to a requested interface and I want to know how I could do this (what options I have). There is also the same base class on each inheritance branch and only one path must be chosen. This seems to work when I return `static_cast` to the nearest unambiguous base and then a user assigns this void pointer to the requested Base. But I can't fully understand why. And another thing I'm interested in whether I can cast an implementation derived to a void pointer straight away and it will always point to the requested Base.

Comment: I don't fully understand your case, but do you really need to cast between base and derived? It seems like you only have to transfer pointers to base and then use them polymorphically without any more casting

Comment: @idclev, the thing is that it is COM's kind of `dynamic_cast` that is implemented manually in order to provide vendor-neutral component architecture. When a user has some base interface to an object, then he can request other interfaces, even unrelated to the current interface (another inheritance branch). So it's not the case when one can get along only with one base interface.

Comment: ...but once you do have the COM base object you no longer need reinterpret_cast

Comment: @idclev, as user — of course. But as implementer I need to know what I can do and what I can't when I cast from the object which is derived from multiple interfaces to any of these interfaces. Particularly, if I can cast to void* itself in order to get the first base.

Comment: The standard doesn't assign defined behaviour to any of these casts. COM however relies on a specific platform ABI, which may give broader guarantees than the standard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point is in definition of standard-layout class.
From http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/type_traits/is_standard_layout/:

A standard-layout class is a class (defined with class, struct or union) that:

- has no virtual functions and no virtual base classes.
- has the same access control (private, protected, public) for all its
  non-static data members.
- either has no non-static data members in the most derived class and
  at most one base class with non-static data members, or has no base
  classes with non-static data members.
- its base class (if any) is itself also a standard-layout class.
- And, has no base classes of the same type as its first non-static
  data member.

In you example class *C* does not match the third rule and so **it is not a standard-layout class**.

Also, about your question about 'or', it applies only to the second part, i.e. after 'or' the statement is still about standard-layout class object, but without non-static members.

Comment: I've looked on cppref and this applies only prior C++14

Comment: now it's _"Has all non-static data members and bit-fields declared in the same class (either all in the derived or all in some base)"_